# Doubling component on "Standard" palette page

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Recently I've installed the new Embarcadero Delphi 10.3 Rio, and noticed that some components on the `Standard` toolbar page are being doubled. Particularly, the doubled components are `TMainMenu`, `TActionList` and others. These components live in Embarcadero's Standard package.

I've looked through the list of installed packages and found some Embarcadero FMX packages with these components. Unchecking those packages (need to uncheck two FMX packages) didn't give a result.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If I let the mouse hover over the 2 MainMenus.  I see "Name: TMainMenu unit: "Vcl.Menus" and "Name: TMainMenu unit:  FMX.Menus"

Comment: On my install copy, I see unit `Vcl.Menus` and the same package on both TMainMenu component icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an IDE bug that affects only components in Standard VCL or FMX package.

Standard VCL controls are displayed twice on the Component toolbar https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19518

[image]

It is harmless, so you don't have to do anything about it.

Which standard package controls will be duplicated (or not at all) depends on the context.

If you don't have any application or package open, you will see both VCL and FMX controls on the toolbar (no duplicates). When you hover with the mouse over the component icon hint will tell you to which package control belongs.

If you have VCL based application or package open, you will have duplicate VCL standard controls. On the other hand if you have FMX based application or package open you will see duplicates from FMX standard controls package.

However, above behavior is not carved in stone. It is just what you can observe most of the time. Component toolbar behavior can be rather unpredictable at times.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Those duplicates are not FMX controls. When you create VCL project FMX controls are not visible. Duplicates here are same VCL controls from standard package.

Comment: But when you hover over them, you do indeed see one with unit Vcl.StdCtrls and one with unit FMX.StdCtrls or so. I even see TScrollbar three times: one VCL, two FMX. But as soon as I start a VCL project, all are VCL and one scrollbar is gone. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis updated the answer, under some circumstances you can have both VCL and FMX controls on the toolbar, but you can also have duplicates of the same controls from standard packages (VCL or FMX)

Comment: Thanks everybody for clearness. Special help to  Rudy Velthuis for editing my question, so it became more readable.